# Excel VBA copy data to txt file - why do you replace the character?

Tags: excel, vba

There is a simple macro that copies all the data on a defined worksheet and saves it in .txt format. The problem is that the decimal number in one of the columns is not separated by a comma but by a dot during the save. I would like to eliminate this somehow, but so far all my attempts have been in vain.

VBA code:

```
Dim myPath As String, myFile As String
    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    myFile = Application.UserName + "_SAP_árlista_betöltő_" + Format(Now(), "YYYY_MM_DD_hhmmss") & ".txt"
    Dim WB As Workbook, newWB As Workbook
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy newWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    With newWB
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs Filename:=myPath & myFile, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
        .Close True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    WB.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A1:J670").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox "Az adatok mentésre kerültek!"
End Sub
```

Thanks for the tips!

Geri

Comment: If you want it separated by a comma would you not use .csv? BTW `activesheet.copy` creates a new workbook with just the copied sheet ,that becomes the active workbook to save.

Comment: I don't want to separate the individual fields with a comma, but there is a specific column whose content is a decimal number that I want to continue to separate with a comma.

Comment: Try changing the format of that column to "Text" before saving to CSV

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately that doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, that's how I managed to solve it.

```
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim strData As String
    Dim strTempFile As String
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    rngData.Copy
    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .GetFromClipboard
        strData = .GetText
    End With
    strTempFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.UserName + "_SAP_árlista_betöltő_" + Format(Now(), "YYYY_MM_DD_hhmmss") & ".txt"
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        .CreateTextFile(strTempFile, True).Write strData
    End With
End Sub
```